# can't get s3 authentication to work to load data into redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, credentials

I'm working on getting data into a sample Redshift cluster for a client, but I can't get authenticated to S3.

There's been a recent change so that my own 'root user' access keys aren't available for this. I tried creating a couple of IAM users (first with 'power user' level, then again with Administrator level) and using those keys, but neither works for either level.

I verified that the format was correct, I thought ...

```
copy gameevents
from 's3://s3.amazonaws.com/motigadata/gamestats_GameEvents_v1.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=keyid;aws_secret_acccess_key=secretID' delimiter ';' null as '(null)';
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid credentials. Must be of the format: credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>;token=<temporary-session-token>'
Detail: error: Invalid credentials. Must be of the format: credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>;token=<temporary-session-token>'
code: 8001
context:
query: 251
location: aws_credentials_parser.cpp:86
process: padbmaster pid=2829
```

The error isn't clear (to me); do I have some syntax error in the credentials setup or are the credentials themselves not accepted?

Finally, I just verified that the S3 bucket has permissions set to let anyone do anything.
So: what's happening?

Help!

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo: 'acccess' in the second access phrase instead of 'access'.

I'd suggest that if anyone from AWS is reading this, a more targeted error
message would have pointed this out to me. Chef's error messages are a shining
example of this sort of thing ...